# synchronized blocks for static and non-static methods

Tags: java, multithreading, static, synchronization

I created two threads and using a single instance of class called the static and non-static methods of that object. Ideally static methods need to be called using the class name and i did that too.

I synchronized both the static and non-static methods on a private static member of the class whose methods the threads are calling. I noticed that the output was synchronized!

My questions are:

1. Static methods if synchronized using a synchronized block it usually requires the class instance, then how did it accept a static object!
2. How was the output synchronized as threads calling static methods acquire the class level lock and threads calling non-static methods acquire object level lock!
   Even though i have used synchronized block in both the static and non-static methods based on an object, it really shouldn't synchronize; or is it special case with synchronized blocks on static objects?

Please let me know.

Following is the code i have written:

```
public class StaticNonStaticSynch 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  final StaticNonStaticTest staticNonStaticTest = new StaticNonStaticTest();

  Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable() 
  {
   @Override
   public void run() 
   {
    staticNonStaticTest.nonStaticMethod();
   }
  };

  Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() 
  {
   @Override
   public void run() 
   {
    staticNonStaticTest.staticMethod();
   }
  };

  Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnable1, "First Thread");
  Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnable2, "Second Thread");

  thread1.start();
  thread2.start();
 }
}

class StaticNonStaticTest
{
 private static Object object = new Object(); 

 void nonStaticMethod()
 {
  synchronized (object) 
  {
   for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
   {
    System.out.println("Non - Static method called by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() +" : = "+i);
   }
  }
 }

 static void staticMethod()
 {
  synchronized (object)
  {
   for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
   {
    System.out.println("Static method called by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() +" : = "+i);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the text properly. Use the 101010 icon for the code snippet.

Comment: _"threads calling non-static methods acquire object level lock"_ they don't acquire object-level lock. The instance method acquires class-level lock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Globally, there exists one instance of the thing called `StaticNonStaticTest.object`. Whenever you synchronize on that thing (**regardless where from**), you are synchronizing on the same lock.

Answer (score -1):

You are synchronizing on the basis of a static object,that's the reason the lock is obtained at the class level and both the static and non-static method's are synchronized.
If you comment out the line "synchronized (object)" in the static and non static method's you can see that the calls are no longer synchronized.